# Tunneling traffic through a proxy using SSH - what does the proxy server see?

Tags: ssh, proxy, privacy, tunnel, socks

If I am accessing information (in a browser or via bittorent) through an SSH tunnel, what info will then be possible to obtain on the SSH/proxy server itself?

As far as I have understood, the information between the proxy server and my computer is encrypted, but is it not possible for the SSH server admin to obtain info about the traffic?

The SSH session requires my credentials, so my guess would be that the server admin would be able to obtain any information about my network usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the proxy server will make connections on your behalf to whatever other IP you request. Even if you encrypt the traffic -- like HTTPS -- the network connections will be visible. If it's plain traffic like HTTP then the proxy server admin will be able to sniff it. More, even if it's HTTPS it's not too hard to launch a man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack by some tricky routing that sends all your HTTP traffic regardless of target IP to a MITM server... You must trust your proxy.